# Numerar líneas en un textarea de html

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código (no recuerdo exactamente donde lo vi, ahí le doy el crédito); lo he tratado de arreglar pero nomás no me ha salido, son dos textarea. Es un textarea donde si escribes te enumera un enunciado y el otro y así.
Yo quisiera hacer eso pero un solo textarea: funciona de a fuerza con los dos textarea, no funciona de otra manera. Ya vi otros métodos que con el botón y no, y aparte traté de hacerlos funcionar sin el botón pero noté que todo se salió de control. ¿Alguien puede echarme la mano y decirme si tiene alguna idea de cómo numerarlo como si estuviéramos trabajando en un Word de Microsoft?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  numeracion();
}

function numeracion(e) {
  let eArea = document.getElementById('areaNumeracion');
  let eArea2 = document.getElementById('txCodigo');
  let numeros = eArea2.value.split("\n").length;
  let msj = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < numeros; i++) {
    msj += (i + 1) + "\n";
  }
  eArea.value = msj;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="areaNumeracion" cols="1" rows="25" readonly></textarea>
  <textarea id="txCodigo" rows="25" cols="70" onkeyup="numeracion(event);"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Para que lo entienda... ¿Quieres un contador de las pulsaciones del teclado fuera del textArea? ¿Dentro? Si tienes algún ejemplo de alguna página donde se vea eso muéstralo y te ayudaremos.

Comment: sin usar dos textarea, solo un textarea nadamas, prueben el codigo y me entenderan de lo que hablo, por ejemplo 1.- soy abril 2.- soy romeo 3.- soy andres y asi, en word le das enter y para enumerar asi te lo grafica en el word

Answer (score 0):

la verdad solo seria necesario traer la longitud del texto contenido en el textarea puedes agregarle algo como "longitud del texto:" o "numero de caracteres:" para que se sepa el contexto de este valor numerico asi:

```js
window.onload = function () {
numeracion();}

function numeracion(e) {
let eArea = document.getElementById('areaNumeracion');
let eArea2 = document.getElementById('txCodigo');
eArea.innerText="Numero de caracteres: "+eArea2.value.length;
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea id="txCodigo" rows="10" cols="70" onkeyup="numeracion(event);"></textarea>
<!-- quite unas cuantas filas para que se vea todo el resultado-->
<h4 id="areaNumeracion"></h4>
</form>
```

Comment: Está muy bien, está perfecto tu ayuda, me acabas de resolver otra duda que por si las dudas la utilizo la tomaré en cuenta muchas gracias, pero lamentable no es esa, si te diste cuenta, enumera así, mira
1.- 2.- 3.-, o sea cuando terminas de escribir el enunciado y le das Enter, enumera el 2, escribes un enunciado, luego el 3, escribes un enunciado, el 4 y así, de todos modos seguiré intentando pero ojalá me ayuden, gracias

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué te parece esta solución? No necesité utilizar nada de **JS**, lo hice todo con **CSS**. Puedes ir escribiendo y a la izquierda tienes el número de línea en el que está.

```css
textarea{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
background-attachment: local;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 35px;
padding-top: 10px;
    border-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Comment: Tiene un "bugcito": cuando el scroll aparece, la numeración de líneas no corre (es decir, siempre figura que la primera línea visible es la 1).

Comment: ¿Ah si? A mi me baja hacia abajo bien :(

Comment: ¿Tal vez usás un navegador basado en Chromium? Lo probé en Firefox.

Comment: Humm no creo, estoy usando Google Chrome

Comment: Chrome está basado en Chromium ;)

Comment: Bueno, pues eso

Comment: en definitiva no, puesto que no marca el numero 1 y 2, es mas ni baja, los numeros estan estaticos, pero bueno, si dices que el problemas es de chrome, a lo mejor en firefox si baja pero igual no creo que lo marque es textarea como para guardarlo en un evento tipo base de datos

Comment: veo que aqui no hay para imagenes si no, les mostraria a todos como me esta ocurriendo el resultado

Comment: miren, les paso a todos el resultado, aquí esta en el link, el de arriba es el que estoy tratando de arreglar, el de abajo es la "solución" de @DarklceDust, está bien pero pues no, miren como van las cosas https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=4919626164722220&set=a.129352220416329

Comment: @ElVecinoTlalixcoyan Bueno, pues lo siento si no te gusta mi solución; tampoco es que explicases mucho lo que querías al principio.